# Best way to store and refer a table of constants using Java

Tags: java

I have data table as below

```
      Column1 | Column 2| Colmun3
 ROW1   AAA   | BBB     | CCC
 ROW2   XXX   | YYY     | ZZZ
 ROW3   PPP   | QQQ     | RRR
```

All AAA, BBB, CCC, XXX, YYY, ZZZ, PPP, QQQ, RRR  will be stored as constants.
Same will be referred at various places in all other modules.

I would like to retrieve constants AAA, BBB etc by calling ROW1.COLUMN1, ROW1.COLMUN2 etc as inputs.

Which Java functions best suit this requirement ? Collections, Enums or any other ? Please provide any relevant example similar to the above.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest data structure to use to retrieve data using a key is a Map.

In this particular situation the key to use is a custom object that has information about object and type.

```
public class MyKey {
    private String object;
    private String type;

    public MyKey(String object, String type) {   
        this.object = object;
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Redefine equals and hashCode functions
}
```

**Important:** If you use a custom key you need to remember to rewrite `hashCode` and equals `functions`.

A simpler solution is to use as key a combination of object and type.
I assumed that what you call object and what you call type are strings. So you can use

```
String key = object + type;
```

or better using a special char

```
String key = object + "$" + type;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Davide's answer. Another option is using a `Map` of `Map` as suggested in the comments, and wrap it in another class where you perform all the null check:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReferenceTable {
    public final static String COL1 = "COL1";
    public final static String COL2 = "COL2";
    public final static String COL3 = "COL3";

    public final static String ROW1 = "ROW1";
    public final static String ROW2 = "ROW2";
    public final static String ROW3 = "ROW3";

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> ref = new HashMap<>();

    {
        put(COL1, ROW1, "AAA");
        put(COL2, ROW1, "BBB");
        put(COL3, ROW1, "CCC");
        // ...
    }

    private void put(String column, String row, String value) {
        Map<String, String> values = ref.get(column);
        if (values == null) {
            values = new HashMap<>();
            ref.put(column, values);
        }
        values.put(row, value);
    }

    public String get(String column, String row) {
        Map<String, String> values = ref.get(column);
        return values == null ? null : values.get(row);
    }
}
```